# Exercise 4, Section 4.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, proof-writing, independence

> If $f$ and $g$ are independent polynomials over the field $F$ and $h$ is a non-zero polynomial over $F$, show that $f\cdot h$ and $g\cdot h$ are independent.

**My attempt:** If $c_1\cdot (f\cdot h)+c_2\cdot (g\cdot h)=0$. By axiom of vector multiplication, $c_1\cdot (f\cdot h)+c_2\cdot (g\cdot h)$ $=(c_1 \cdot f)\cdot h+ (c_2 \cdot g)\cdot h$ $=(c_1\cdot f+c_2\cdot g)\cdot h$ $=0$. Since $h\neq 0$, we have $c_1\cdot f+c_2\cdot g=0$, by theorem 1 section 4.2. Since $\{f,g\}$ is independent, we have $c_1$ $=c_2$ $=0$. Hence $\{f\cdot h\text{, }g\cdot h\}$ is independent. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: You've got some $g$s where you want $h$s, like $f\cdot g$. Also theorem 1, section 4.2 is just the statement that if $f$ and $g$ are non-zero polynomials over $F$ then $fg$ is a non-zero polynomial, so you might as well just type that out.

Comment: There is a misprint, should be $c_1(fh)$ at two places.